# To disable all languages other than english from keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin, mobile

I want to avoid other languages, I want an English keyboard to use as an input.

```
<TextInput
    style={{ width: "85%", marginStart: 10, fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Roboto' }}
    placeholder="Enter your password"
    onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
    secureTextEntry={!showPassword} />
```

Answer (score 0):

**use "keyboardType="email-address"" prop in TextInput**

force enable only english language from keyboard in react native